# Chinese remainder theorem, how to get a ≡ b (mod pq) from a ≡ b (mod p) and a ≡ b (mod q)?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

> a ≡ b (mod p)
>   a ≡ b (mod q)
>   
>   **Then :** a ≡ b (mod pq)

Can someone explain this to me ? I was told it was from *Chinese Remainder Theorem*.
Is there an easy way to get the third line, given the first two lines ?

Note that I read [this answer to an other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1942177/505410) and didn't understand anything, so please provide an easily understandable answer.

Comment: is it given that $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes?

Comment: it is not, but an example with distinct primes was provided with it (12 and 7 mod 35)

Comment: possible duplicate:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942154/number-theory-a-%E2%89%A1-b-mod-p-and-a-%E2%89%A1-b-mod-q-show-that-a-%E2%89%A1-b-mod

Comment: @DaríoA.Gutiérrez I said in my post that I read that and I needed a simpler answer that anyone could example, instead of these complexe notations

Answer (score 2):

Definition of lcm$(x,y)$.

$\qquad (1.) \quad x \mid \operatorname{lcm}(x,y).$

$\qquad (2.) \quad y \mid \operatorname{lcm}(x,y).$

$\qquad (3.) \quad \text{If $x \mid z$ and $y \mid z$ then 
                         $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y) \mid z.$}$

---

Theorem. $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y) = \dfrac{xy}{\gcd(x,y)}$.

---

Theorem. Suppose $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime. Then $p \mid n$ and $q \mid n$ implies $pq \mid n$.

Proof. If $p \mid n$ and $q \mid n$, then $\operatorname{lcm}(p,q) \mid n$. Since  $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime,
$\operatorname{lcm}(p,q) = \dfrac{pq}{\gcd(p,q)} = pq$. Hence $pq \mid n$.

---

Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are relative prime.

If $a \equiv b \pmod p$ and  $a \equiv b \pmod q$, then $p \mid (b-a)$ and 
$q \mid (b-a)$. Since $p$ and $q$ are relative prime, then $pq \mid (b-a)$.
Hence $a \equiv b \pmod{pq}$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* If $p$ divides $c$ and $q$ divides $c$, then $pq=lcm(p,q)$ divides $c$.

(This assumes that $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes or at least are coprime.)

Comment: if p and q are distinct primes, how could c be different to 1 ?

Comment: @PaulLemarchand, $c$ can be $0, pq, 2pq, \dots $ but $c$ cannot be $1$.

Comment: oh right, in my language divides means p is the numerator, but I guess it's the other way around. But how could I demonstrate that ?